# Drag and drop only child (future handle)

Tags: javascript, events, parent, handle

I have problem with drag and drop, because my handle will be create in the future:

```
  drawCharts(tableLetters) {
    let countryCharts = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < tableLetters.length; i++) {
        countryCharts += `
      <div class ="dropzone">
        <div class="countryChart" draggable="true"><span class="letters">${tableLetters[i]}</div>
      </div>
      `
    }
    this.charts.innerHTML = countryCharts;
    this.deleteEmptySquare();
  }
```

I tried set handle as a parent, but this works wrong. I wanna set events only for child, not for parent. I try turn off the reaction of the parent, but i can't.

```
  drag() {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('countryCharts') || event.target.classList.contains('dropzone') || event.target.classList.contains('letters')) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  dragStart() {
    this.dragged = event.target;
    if (this.dragged.classList.contains('countryCharts') || this.dragged.classList.contains('dropzone') || this.dragged.classList.contains('letters')) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

PS. DRY is not important right now.